# How to display image pointed by URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I have a image here http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg and I want to display it in my Rails site. How should i do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can also use the action view `image_tag` helper:

```
<%= image_tag 'http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg' %>
```

Alternatively you can just use the regular HTML tags:

**ERB:**

```
<img src="http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg">
```

**Haml:**

```
%img{ src: "http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg" }
```

**Slim:**

```
img src="http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg"
```

Comment: This works, but if there is no dinamic involved, the static version of the tag (like pierr's) shall save you some millisecons on rendering, which of course you only matter if you have millions of visitors and load is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

<%= link_to image_tag post.image %>

Answer (score 1):

Put the URL into an img tag inside the view for the page that should display the image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the image didn't show until I added `alt` attribute. So if that didn't work I think you can try this way.

```
<%= image_tag 'http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg', alt: 'fun' %>
```

Answer (score -5):

Tested and worked.

```
<img src="http://power.itp.ac.cn/~jmyang/funny/fun4.jpg", width="500" , height="400"> </img>
```

Comment: What was your previous attempt? :-/

Comment: Images don't have a closing tag like that... `<img />`