# How to call an external website image with image_tag in a .html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I call an image of some url external website using image_tag in a rails html view? Please, I'm looking for an alternative using image_tag not the regular html or css

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582950/how-to-display-image-pointed-by-url-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**  Turns out OP wanted to do this b/c Heroku wasn't pulling in images from the assets folder. It is an issue that is easily resolved by reading/following the instructions here: [Rails 4 images not loading on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku) .

Leaving the original answer here as it more correctly answers the original question.

`image_tag` works with full urls. So you could just give it the URL to the site you want to pull from. i.e:

```
<%= image_tag 'https://placekitten.com/800/400' %>
```

I'm sure you are already aware of this, but in 99.999% of situations, hot-linking images from other sites is a very bad idea.

Comment: hi thanks for you answer, your'e totally right, but heroku is simply not showing images I call from my images folder

Comment: AH! that is a different issue all together. It is a bit complicated (heroku vs the asset pipeline), but the fix is easy. Just add this to your gemfile: ```rails_12factor```. Here is a better SO question/answer to walk you through it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an SVG file that is the image and it points to your Github or Linkedin profile, you could do something like this:

Setup:

1. In app/images/, you have some image file. For example, linkedin.svg.

Procedure

2. In your html.erb file, add:

---

```
<%= link_to image_tag("linkedin.svg"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile",  :target => "_blank"%>
```

3. Wait!!!!! READ CAREFULLY
   Pay close attention to the space between image_tag and the parentheses(the method and the argument).
   Some examples that you'll find online show a space between the image_tag and the argument. Keep them together.
4. Check the commas.
5. Last, just to be safe, make sure your link includes `"http://www....."`